# How to return a function in a function in php?

Tags: php, function

I would like to have the functionality to set a function  in a class (function `setFunction`). Later I want to get the function (with `getFunction`), which I can call from outside (specifying parameters etc. ). Here is what I have tried:

```
class Test
{
    var $function;

    function setFunction($foo)
    {
        $this->function = $foo;
    }

    function getFunction()
    {
        return $this->function;
    }

    function foo1($a)
    {
        print "foo1: ".$a."\n"; 
    }

    function foo2($b)
    {
        print "foo2: ".$b."\n"; 
        }

}

$oClass = new Test();
$oClass->setFunction($oClass->foo1);
$oClass->getFunction()('test'); # <--- line 32
```

The expected output is

```
foo1: test
```

But I get an error instead:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in tester.php on line 32
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Here are some constraints:

- This has to work for arbitrary parameters for each function.
- The function to be defined is always specified in the class itself (if that helps).

Comment: Are you really still working with PHP4 or did you just mess up your tags? Also, have a look at [callables in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: Yes, PHP4 is a requirement.

Comment: @Alex: Even you need PHP 4 code, the question per-se is not specific to PHP 4 therefore I removed the tag. I hope this is okay with you and write this just in case you wonder.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$oClass = new Test();
$oClass->setFunction(array($oClass, 'foo1'));
call_user_func($oClass->getFunction(), 'test');
```

`array($oClass, 'foo1')` is a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), which represents an invocation of method `foo1` on class instance `$oClass`.

Answer (score -1):

function in php is not a object what so ever. you can not do in this way.